# How to change port mapping when linking Docker containers

Tags: docker

Is it possible to change the port mapping of two Docker containers when linking them?

I have one image running an application container that exposes port 8081 (called `app`). The other image needs to access this application container (called `consumer`).

Now I can easily do:

```
docker run --name app app
docker run --link=app consumer
```

This will allow me to access `app` with `tcp://app:8081`.

Unfortunately, both applications have hardcoded settings for the ports. `app` will only run on 8081, consumer must access `app` on 8080.

Can I change the port mapping so that `app` is available to `consumer` on port 8080? Similar to `--publish=8080:8081` but for container linking.

Comment: Nope. this is not possible. You can always expose app container on 8081 & 8080, `docker run -p <host_port1>:<container_port1> -p <host_port2>:<container_port2> app`.

Comment: What applications are these that can't bind to different ports?

Comment: @JHarris Technically the port can be changed, but for legacy reasons this would require a rather large rewrite, so I first wanted to check if there is another way.

Comment: @Shibashis Will this have any effect on the port where `consumer` will be able to reach `app`?

Comment: `docker run -p 8081:8081 -p8080:8081 app`, will ensure the same service is exposed in multiple ports.